# How can extract from OpenFileDialog the files path name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void addGifsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            theDialog.Title = "Add Gif Files";
            theDialog.Filter = "GIF files|*.gif";
            theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            theDialog.Multiselect = true;
            if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] files = theDialog.SafeFileNames;
                    allfiles = new List<string>(files);
                    label2.Text = allfiles.Count.ToString();
                    if (allfiles.Count > 1)
                    {
                        button2.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allfiles = new List<string>();
                label2.Text = "0";
            }
        }
```

All the added files from the same directory i need somehow to get the files directory name each time i click OK

After the line: label2.Text = "0"; to get the files directory path.

Comment: what to you mean? after you click Ok you go into `if` part not `else` part

Comment: I mean in the dialog i'm going to a directory select files then click ok i want to get the directory the file are in in a string variable. For example: i selected 4 files from c:\ so now in allfiles i will see 1.gif,2.gif,3.gif....now i want in another variable for example selectedpath to see c:\ and if for example i went to e:\myimages and selected there some files i will see in allfiles: 1.gif,2.gif,3.gif nut now in selectedpath i will see e:\myimages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the name of the directory for any given file path:

```
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theDialog.FileName);
```

or:

```
foreach(string file in theDialog.FileNames)
{
    directoryNameList.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
}
```